# How to form XFD from cobol Data

Tags: cobol

I'll try to redefine the XFD file structure based on below file settings option

```
Anaylsis Result:

Max Record length 300
Min record length 61
No of records 466
Blocking factor 1
Preallocation amount 0
Extension amount 1
Compression factor 80
Encrypted ? No
Number of keys 4
Primary key has 1 segments
key size 13 offset 0

key 02 has 3 segments
Duplicates Are allowed
Key size 4 offset 4
Key size 40 offset 21
Key size 4 offset 0

Key 03 has 3 segments
Duplicates Are allowed
Key size 4 offset 4
Key size 8 offset 13
Key size 4 offset 0

Key04 has 1 segment
Duplicates Are allowed
Key size 10 offset 21
```

Another given XFD file structure which is already failed to obtained data from AcuODBC:
I 'm linking against from pote.XFD to pote Acu database file through ACUODBC.

```
XFD,02,POTE,POTE
00026,00018,002
1,0,008,00000
02
INTIND-UNIQ
INTIND-OCC
1,1,010,00008
01
IND16
000
0004,00004
00000,00004,12,00009,+00,000,000,INTIND-UNIQ
00004,00004,12,00009,+00,000,000,INTIND-OCC
00008,00010,16,00010,+00,000,000,IND16
00018,00008,16,00008,+00,000,000,TERM20
```

I'm linking against from pote.XFD to pote Acu database file through ACUODBC. 
My Question is here how could I change my pote.XFD structure based on give analysis as given on top to form a correct XFD structure.

I know there are four keys in this cobol table, but I still don't know how to manually configure this data structure based on given analysis information.

Below is another reference guide on how to form XFD correct structure in manual where I've already obtained, hope someone expert can help to explained the way on how to form on correct XFD structure.

```
# This xfd layout is a generic one suitable for accessing any 
# .DAD file. However, it needs to be copied and amended for each 
# DAD file that you wish to get access to. 
# The simplest scenario is that you copy dad.xfd to a new file 
# with the same name as the database you wish to access and extension .XFD 
# Then edit this new file and replace the two instances of 'FILE' with the 
# filename that you want to access. e.g. if you want to have ODBC access to 
# icvc.dad then copy dad.xfd to new file icvc.xfd and change line 
#   XFD,02,FILE,FILE            to be 
#   XFD,02,ICVC,ICVC 
# 
# If this doesn't work then the database file you are trying to access has 
# probably set different values for search index sizes. The easiest way to 
# check this is to run $list for the database that you want to access and 
# note down all the key information that it gives. If that is different 
# to the key info in this file then you need to modify the xfd file to match 
# In the current xfd there are four indexes defined. In all cases the first 
# index will be correct and so should the third index. However, the other 
# two may need to be modified or removed if not present. 
# Index 4 is optional and is not present if the database is rebuilt without 
# the fast list option. 
# explaining the details of 2nd index. 1 st line consists of 8 values separated 
# by commas. The first value of 3 is how many segments the index consists of. 
# second value 1 means duplicates allowed (0 means NO DUPS). 
# The remaining six fields are three pairs of key size and byte offset, e.g. 
# first index segment is 4 bytes long and starts from byte 4, second index 
# segment is 20 bytes long and starts from byte 21 etc. 
# The second line specifies how many field names there are to follow and lines 3 
# to 5 are the three field names as defined lower in this xfd. For instance 
# if you look at field D1UNIQ you will see it is defined as starting from byte 0 
# and is 4 bytes long. This corresponds to the values entered in the key definition. 
# 
XFD,02,ICVC,ICVC 
00300,00041,004 
# [Key Section] 
# [1st index] 
01,0,013,00000 
04 
D1UNIQ 
D1NAME 
D1NAMX 
D1OCCU 
# [2nd index] 
3,1,004,00004,020,00021,004,00000 
03 
D1NAME 
D1TUPP 
D1UNIQ 
# [3rd index] 
3,1,004,00004,008,00013,004,00000 
03 
D1NAME 
D1NUMB 
D1UNIQ 
# [4th index] 
1,1,020,00021 
01 
D1TUPP 
# [Condition Section] 
000 
# [Field Section] 
0015,00015,00016 
00000,00013,16,00013,+00,000,999,D1KEY 
00000,00004,12,00009,+00,000,000,D1UNIQ 
00004,00004,16,00004,+00,000,000,D1NAME 
00008,00001,16,00001,+00,000,000,D1NAMX 
00009,00004,12,00009,+00,000,000,D1OCCU 
00013,00008,11,00018,-06,000,000,D1NUMB 
00021,00040,16,00040,+00,000,000,D1TUPP 
00061,00001,01,00001,+00,000,000,D1GRAD 
00062,00004,12,00008,+00,000,000,D1DLUP 
00066,00004,12,00008,+00,000,000,D1TLUP 
00070,00004,16,00004,+00,000,000,D1OLUP 
00074,00001,16,00001,+00,000,000,D1TYPE 
00075,00002,16,00002,+00,000,000,D1FORM 
00077,00160,16,00160,+00,000,000,D1TEXT 
00237,00001,16,00001,+00,000,000,D1PRIN 
00238,00062,16,00062,+00,000,000,D1FILL
```

Comment: Try Googing [xfd acucobol](https://www.google.ca/#q=xfd+acucobol) and follow up on the links.

Answer (score 0):

First do this:

> '# This xfd layout is a generic one suitable for accessing any 
>   '# .DAD file. However, it needs to be copied and amended for each 
>   '# DAD file that you wish to get access to. 
>   '# The simplest scenario is that you copy dad.xfd to a new file 
>   '# with the same name as the database you wish to access and extension .XFD 
>   '# Then edit this new file and replace the two instances of 'FILE' with the 
>   '# filename that you want to access. e.g. if you want to have ODBC access to 
>   '# icvc.dad then copy dad.xfd to new file icvc.xfd and change line 
>   '#   XFD,02,FILE,FILE            to be 
>   '#   XFD,02,ICVC,ICVC

If that does not work, follow the instructions for finding out how many keys ther are and the values for the second key. If you discover there are only three keys, remove the fourth key from the template. If the values for the second key are different, change them in the [FieldSection].

Get it working before changing anything else.

Comment: I can check the number of first , second (alternate key) structures by using "vutil32 -info -k -x icvc".                               3,1,004,00004,020,00021,004,00000 , 3 stands for 3 key exists, 1 stands for no duplicate allowed, The rest begin with "0" can be obtained from commands given at above.

Comment: But there is still no enough, I need to knowed the actual Field Descriptor along their occur points and length to form a correct XFD structure. Without this I could'n be able to link into Acucobol data table, but I din't have any source code. Is that have any alternate way by using any open system tools or Reverse Engineering techniques in expliant to help me find out on these FD information?

Comment: If you have tried what I said and it failed, update your question to include exactly what you tried and exactly how it failed. If you have not tried what I said, try it.