# how to form fields section in xfd file

Tags: cobol, gnucobol, microfocus

I'm having problem to form the field section's structure into xfd files after analyse by issuing commnad "vutil32.exe -i -kx pogl.dad". I hope somebody could help me out how to form out field structure as highlighted in below. I've uploaded sample of my file known as "pglc.dad" i hope soneone could guide me how to form .xfd file from his expert skills and guide me.Thanks

Result from vutil32.exe

```
file size: 250880
record size (min/max): 121/1024 compressed(80%)
# of keys: 4
key size: 16:02 31:03 56:03 15
key offset: 0 0 0 1
duplicates okay: N N N N

block size: 512
blocks per granule: 1
tree height: 4/2/2.7
# of nodes: 200
# of deleted nodes: 1
total node space: 101800
node space used: 67463 (66%)
user count: 0

Key Dups Seg-1 Seg-2 Seg-3 Seg-4 Seg-5 Seg-6
(sz/of) (sz/of) (sz/of) (sz/of) (sz/of) (sz/of)

0 N 1/0 15/1
1 N 1/0 15/66 15/1
2 N 1/0 40/81 15/1
3 N 15/1

Here is my further construction of .xfd file.
XFD,02,PGLC,PGLC
00300,00041,004
1,0,013,00000
01
PGSTAT
3,0,004,00004,020,00021,004,00000
3
PGSTAT
PGDESC
PGLINE
3,0,004,00004,008,00013,004,00000
03
PGSTAT
PGDESC
PGLINE
1,0,012,00021
01
PGSTAT
000
0150,00150,00003 =================>> How can i form this field section.
00000,00013,16,00016,+00,000,000,PGSTAT
00000,00001,16,00001,+00,000,000,PGDESC
00001,00015,16,00015,+00,000,000,PGLINE
```

here is the link for my pglc.dad : http://files.engineering.com/getfile.aspx?folder=080fdad6-b1d5-4a37-8dd0-b89f9a985c69&file=PGLC.DAD

Thanks appopriate to someone could helps.

Comment: Have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18767244/1927206/ Other than that, you'll have to make your question a lot clearer. For problems, your best bet would be to contact Micro Focus support: it is there job, and they have experience of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the XFD format intimately as I have written a couple of parsers of this file format in both Perl and Cobol.

Having said that, I would strongly recommend that you do **not** try to hand craft an XFD file from scratch.

If you have an AcuCobol (MicroFocus) compiler, and the source of the file's `SELECT` and `FD` definitions, then you can create a very small Cobol program that has just the `SELECT` and `FD` definitions and then compile the program using:

```
ccbl32.exe -Fx <program>
```

That will create an XFD file for the indexed file definition. Note, you can specify a directory for the created XFD file using the `-Fo <directory>` option.

If you don't have the source of the file definitions, then you are just going to be guessing what and where the fields are. The indexed file by itself will not tell you that information. I can see from extracting the data in your file (using the `vutil -e` option) that the file contains binary data as well as text, so without knowing exactly what PICture those fields are (COMP-?) you will be struggling to figure out the structure of those fields.